# What is best way to see data format in hadoop hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

Loaded nearly 50GB of CSV file into Hadoop cluster and I want to see some sample records for identifying the columns.

I have tried using

```
hadoop fs -cat employees.csv | head -n 10
```

My questions are

1. is that right command to see the data ?
2. `head -n 10` - it will load 50 GB data and it will do filter first 10 lines? how it is working ?
3. any other better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on your version.

For older Hadoop (< 3.1.0) versions:

```
hadoop fs -cat employees.csv | head -n 10
```

For newer (>= 3.1.0) Hadoop versions

```
 hadoop fs -head employees.csv
```

Comment: thanks for you reply. i am using < 3.1.0 version. in that case i have to use this command : hadoop fs -cat employees.csv | head -n 10 - how will it work.. loading entire data and do head command or loading time . need to check performance side..